# Duplicate unique primary key error Teradata - Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, teradata

all of a sudden we are seeing this issue Duplicate unique primary key issue, we are using Teradata and hibernate in java service.
@ID has been used on a column with strategy Increment. In Teradata, the column is just defined as a not-null decimal and as primary key

Teradata Dialect only supports increment strategy I believe, Sequence is not supported.
This used to work for a while, all of a sudden issue started appearing. Trying to figuring out what could cause this to break.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. But it sounds to me like either the definition for your table changed, or your code isn't correctly identifying when to update vs insert.

Comment: Perhaps values have overflowed the precision of the field? Is the value being generated by Hibernate or does the Teradata definition contain a GENERATED clause?

Comment: @Fred values are generated by Hibernate only. Table in Teradata is just defined that column as Not Null , decimal..  and primary key constraint on that table.

Comment: @Andrew Table DDL has not being changed.